# Change Background Image using JQuery is successful but how to make one image default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery and, using it, I am changing my `body` `background-image` but how to make one image default when the page loads:

This is my jQuery under the head tag

```
var backImage = new Array();

backImage[0] = "images/1.jpg"; 

backImage[1] = "images/2.jpg"; 

backImage[2] = "images/3.jpg";

function changeBGImage(whichImage)

{ 

if (document.body){ 

document.body.background = backImage[whichImage]; 

}
```

links - clicking on this the background image changes:

```
<a href="javascript:changeBGImage(0)">1</a>
<a href="javascript:changeBGImage(1)">2</a>
<a href="javascript:changeBGImage(2)">3</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could launch the function when the page loads using the default image index.

For example

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    changeBGImage(0);
});
```

or maybe if you want to set it before hand, you could just add it to the styles of the body tag

```
<body style="background-image:url(...);">
```